# postfix and anvil- rate limiting?

Tags: centos, postfix

I am having some troubles with postfix.
I am using it currently for SMTP only, and it was working fine. Then it stopped working. The log wasn't showing anything at all so I am unsure if it was a connection issue or not.

The logs are showing this howefver:

```
Aug 30 16:25:14 westc01-01-01 postfix/anvil[14400]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:203.43.xxx.2xx) at Aug 30 16:21:50
Aug 30 16:25:14 westc01-01-01 postfix/anvil[14400]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:203.43.xxx.2xx) at Aug 30 16:21:50
Aug 30 16:25:14 westc01-01-01 postfix/anvil[14400]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Aug 30 16:21:50
```

What does this mean? Does this mean that Anvil is limited the amount of email that can be sent through the system? Could this be why email just stopped sending, with it sitting in Outlook? This is a newly configured mail server so i'm sure there are many things wrong at the moment.
Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

That's statistical info level logging by `anvil` (postfix's rate limiting controller). It by itself does not indicate any problem or blocking of messages.

Rate limit log line example:

```
Aug 29 10:37:12 mta1 postfix/smtpd[11166]: warning: Connection rate limit exceeded: 11 from unknown[124.229.43.103] for service smtp
```

Note: `mynetworks` is generally excluded from `anvil`'s rate limiting.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> postfix/anvil[14400]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:203.43.xxx.2xx) at Aug 30 16:21:50
> postfix/anvil[14400]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:203.43.xxx.2xx) at Aug 30 16:21:50
> postfix/anvil[14400]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Aug 30 16:21:50
> ```
>
> What does this mean? Does this mean that Anvil is limited the amount
>   of email that can be sent through the system?

It means that you've exceeded the maximum number of errors a remote SMTP client is allowed to make without delivering mail.

Take a look at the following directives:

- [`smtpd_error_sleep_time`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_error_sleep_time)
- [`smtpd_soft_error_limit`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_soft_error_limit)
- [`smtpd_hard_error_limit`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_hard_error_limit)

Show us the value of these paramaters in your `main.cf`? Post some lines above those messages?

Comment: Hi. How do you output the configuration? I've seen the command on the internet but forgot! I checked main.cf but none of those exist in main.cf

Comment: `postconf <parameter>`.