# How to deal with outgoing spam flooding with Postfix

Tags: postfix, spam

I have one Postfix SMTP server with hundreds of users, which are using it to send e-mails as authenticated users.

Sometimes one account is hacked and thousand e-mails become to go out from the SMTP server, starting a spam flooding to hundreds of e-mail addresses.

This obviously make my server to be inserted into many blacklist and when I realise  I need to:

- fix the hacked account (and educate users to use good password and to change them frequently)
- stop the flooding removing spam messages from the outgoing queue
- check the IP address into blacklists and remove them if needed
- monitor outgoing e-mails to check if they are marked as spam

Now I want to understand how I can efficiently prevent the flooding before it happens, because we cannot risk to be inserted into any blacklist. I think this could be reached with:

- force users to use a good password: this can be easily reached if you are using an authentication backend like Active Directory, but what about Postfix users and virtual domains saved into the database?
- activating fail2ban on SMTP services (but this does not work if hackers already know passwords and use them at the first try)
- implementing some flooding detection like outgoing rate detection for the same users which could stop relay for a specific user if it's spamming: what technology can be used on top of Postfix to achieve this?
- monitoring: some Nagios/Icinga checks for the elements in the Postfix outgoing queue (but could be too late)
- monitoring: a lot of services which can check if the IP address is into some blacklist (but too late)

Any other idea?

Comment: My first experience with LDAP was with the ancient ancestor of 389-ds, and the directory passwords were initially seeded from a unix shadow password file. These passwords needed to be marked {crypt} when they were set, but it worked, and provided a graceful transition from local passwords to network passwords. I would expect other password databases and other LDAP servers could be handled in a similar fashion. (Similar, not exactly the same. The specific differences would need to be worked out.)

Comment: I was a postmaster for most of the prior decade, but reorged out of that position about 11 years ago. At that time, I was frustrated with the dearth of tools to detect and block spam flooding from a local user to outside. Reading this question, I thought, surely things have improved by this point. I thought this would be an easy google search by this point. I was clearly wrong. To me, it's simple; if you want to stop spam, support ISPs blocking it before they send it.

Comment: Question: how does client email get to your server? Does it enter through the same SMTP port as external email, does it get placed on postfix's pickup queue like it was generated locally on the server, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

SASL-authenticated clients using your mail server to send out spam or malware are usually the result of botnets. You can catch most if not all of botnet-like behaviour using postfwd rules and the [Postfwd Anti Geoip Spam Plugin](https://github.com/Vnet-as/postfwd-anti-geoip-spam-plugin) which will check for both high rates of sending as well as logins from more than one country or IP address.

Once you have installed [postfwd](https://github.com/postfwd/postfwd) and the plugin, you can configure rules which will block senders once they exceed certain limits.

A typical rate limiting ruleset might look like this (anti-botnet rules are given in the instructions for the Anti Geoip Spam Plugin link above):

```
id=R005; action=dunno ; client_name=friendly\.mailserver\.org\.uk$
id=R010; sender=~/.+/; action=rate(sender/100/86400/REJECT only 100 messages per day for sender [$$sender])
id=R020; sender=~/.+/; action=rate(sender/25/3600/REJECT only 25 messages per hour for sender [$$sender])
id=R030; sasl_username=~/.+/; action=rate(sasl_username/100/86400/REJECT only 100 messages per day for auth user [$$sasl_username])
id=R040; sasl_username=~/.+/; action=rate(sasl_username/25/3600/REJECT only 25 messages per hour for auth user [$$sasl_username])
id=R050; user=~/.+/; action=rate(user/100/86400/REJECT only 100 messages per day for user [$$user])
id=R060; user=~/.+/; action=rate(user/25/3600/REJECT only 25 messages per hour for user [$$user])
```

Answer (score -1):

Search for “postfix anvil”. It provides rate limiting features for outbound. it is effective in mitigating reputation issues when an account is compromised.

Comment: Anvil relates to sending mail *in* from remote SMTP clients, not *out* via SASL-auth from a machine on `$mynetworks`, which is what this question refers to.

Comment: My friend, the question is about email sent from authenticated users.

Comment: Indeed - *outgoing* authenticated users. Unless you know of a way of configuring anvil to do that, in which case please expand your answer.

Comment: No special configuration is needed for authenticated users connecting from ip addresses that are not in $mynetworks. Limits are IP based. Any configuration you do will apply to authenticated users too.  

This is an example of daily limits.  

    anvil_rate_time_unit = 24h. 
    smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 1500  
    smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 1500  
    smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 1500  
    smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 1500  
    smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 1500

Comment: OK, so please expand your answer to explain that. My understanding from the documentation for anvil was that outgoing mail from $mynetworks were excluded from the anvil rules (https://serverfault.com/questions/422765/postfix-and-anvil-rate-limiting)

Comment: Sending as an authenticated user is not the same as sending from $mynetworks. SMTP authentication is not $mynetworks.